# Create two lists in one line?

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe

Is there a nicer way to write this ?

df is a pandas dataframe. `df_book` and `df_payd` are two `pandas` dataframe I am trying to build based on the columns of df. This code does the job, however I am looking for the nicest options.

```
sp = df.shape[1]/2
col1,col2 = df.columns[:sp],df.columns[sp:]
df_book,df_payd = df[col1],df[col2]
```

Comment: what do you do if you have an odd number of columns?

Comment: not much wrong with this approach IMO

Comment: @riotburn it cannot happen in my case. But well spotted. How would you handle the matter ?

Comment: i would round up or down based on my use case if it made sense.  But like @EdChum says, I don't anything wrong with this.  If you wanted, you could combine the last two lines since it wouldn't be too verbose.